# Download image from external source php not working in server

Tags: php, curl

I'm unable to download image from external source using curl,php in server(for some images only).

> It is giving "failed to open stream: Connection timed out" error

```
function getHeaders($url)
{
   $ch = curl_init($url);
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
   curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 3 );
  curl_exec( $ch );
  $headers = curl_getinfo( $ch );
  curl_close( $ch );    
  return $headers;
}

    function download($url, $path)
{
  # open file to write
  $fp = fopen ($path, 'w+');
  # start curl
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
  # set return transfer to false
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true );
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
  # increase timeout to download big file
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10 );
  # write data to local file
  curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp );
  # execute curl
  curl_exec( $ch );
  # close curl
  curl_close( $ch );
  # close local file
  fclose( $fp );

  if (filesize($path) > 0) return true;
}

$url = 'http://81.144.197.80:8998/image-bb?imageid=190590';
$path = 'uploads/file.jpg';

$headers = getHeaders($url);

if ($headers['http_code'] === 200 and $headers['download_content_length'] < 1024*1024) {
  if (download($url, $path)){
    echo 'Download complete!'; 
  }
}
```

I'm able to download it from `localhost`

Please help me.

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: If you don't show the code, it is hard to help you

Comment: Welcome to stack : check how to ask a question on stack :- http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask